# Specs/Stats displaying on Homescreen on Galaxy S II 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings

Having the following showing up on all home screens in the background. Any ideas why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out your Live Wallpaper. Does restarting help?

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a widget displaying system information. Tap-and-hold it, a trashcan icon should appear on your screen (most likely on the top, and most likely marked red). Drag the widget onto it, and let it go. This will remove it from the homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Factory Test Mode. You can remove it, but you need to have root access.

If you have root, do these:

- Open a terminal emulator (e.g. [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm))
- Type su
- Then enter the following after the #
- echo -n ON > /efs/FactoryApp/factorymode

*Yes, ON is the correct setting to turn it off.* Exit the terminal, and reboot the phone.

[Reference](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=28815755&postcount=349).

**If that doesn't work**, you may need to re-flash the ROM.